# Selector doesn't change color on API higher then 21

Tags: android, selector

I need to change color of the ImageButton when user pressing it. It works as I expect on APIs 19 and 21 but on API higher then 21 it doesn't and I can't understand why.

Here is XML of selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="100dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="#427A53"
                />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="60dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="100dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="#66bb6a"
                />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="60dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Do post your solution as answer and accept it. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Problem was in `android:backgroundTint` attribute of ImageButton, it was the same color and it was "blocking" change of color.

Answer (score 0):

bcz selector working lower than api 21, for higher version you can use like this..

```
 RippleDrawable rippleImgStart;  
 final int ColorWhiteOpacity = Color.argb(75,255,255,255); 
 imgStart = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.start); 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            rippleImgStart = new
                    RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(ColorWhiteOpacity), imgStart, null);
            btnselectvideo.setImageDrawable(rippleImgStart);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem in a little bit easier way.

Comment: in your solution its change your imagebutton color only.. but in my solution you can also provide ripple too.., well you are welcome